Fourier transform of a function involving Bessel functions
During my research in EM scattering (specifically floquet analysis of complicated structures), I came upon the following integral which I haven't been able to solve.
If anybody has any idea it would be great.
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d \bar{y} \frac{\bar{y}}{\sqrt{x^2+\bar{y} ^2}}\cdot \frac{e^{-i\cdot k\cdot \sqrt{x^2+\bar{y}^2+z^2})}}{\sqrt{x^2+\bar{y} ^2+z^2}} \cdot J_{1}(ka\cdot \sqrt{\frac{{x^2+\bar{y} ^2}}{{{x^2+\bar{y} ^2+z^2}}}}) \cdot e^{-i\cdot k_{t,m}\cdot \bar{y}}$
where $x$,$z$,$k$,$a$ and $k_{t,m}$ are real constants, and $J_1$ is the Bessel function of the first kind.
